# tocloft and width of the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, classicthesis

In the `ClassicThesis` class, the table of contents is set up through the `tocloft` package and I cannot find a way to line up the page numbers (on the right) as shown below with the thick red line. I'd like the blue numbers to be lined up to the right with the upper line. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example code contains the necessary redefinitions:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,ngerman,american]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\hfill}
\input{classicthesis-config}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, take into account the following remark conatined in the documentation of `classicthesis`:

> And last but not least, to provide the reader with a way easier access
>   to page numbers in the table of contents, the page numbers are right
>   behind the titles. Yes, they are not neatly aligned at the right side
>   and they are not connected with dots that help the eye to bridge a
>   distance that is not necessary. If you are still not convinced: is
>   your reader interested in the page number or does she want to sum the
>   numbers up?
>
> Therefore, please do not break the beauty of the style by changing
>   these things unless you really know what you are doing! Please.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I am aware of the quote but I do not agree with it. The non-aligned set-up somehow provides a chaotic TOC, I think. I still agree that all this probably depends on each of us.